# write() over a socket handles const char * incorrectly

Tags: c, sockets, char

I'm writing a simple TCP/IP client and I wanted to send some pre-written messages (some short strings, like login and password). And I stumbled upon some code and refactored it slightly. But I can't use `write` in this manner.

When I use fgets it looks something like this:

```
 LOGIN
 somelogin
 PASS
 somepass
 OK
```

and so on.

But using
`err = write(sockfd, "name", 5);` doesn't seem to get a reply from server.

```
LOGIN
(nothing happens)
```

`join()` is really just connecting to the host

`error()` is writing the message and exiting

Main:

```
int sockfd, err;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
struct hostent *server;
char buffer[256];

int main(int argc,  char *argv[])
{
    join();

    while(true)
    {
        err = read(sockfd, buffer, 255);
        if(err < 0) 
             error("ERROR reading from socket");
        printf("%s", buffer);
        bzero(buffer, 256);
        fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);
        err = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
        if(err < 0) 
            error("ERROR writing to socket");
        bzero(buffer, 256);  
    }
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

I guess it has to do with the `write` function and the type of buff.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [sigh] 'printf("%s", buffer);' on a buffer that is not guaranteed null-terminated:(

Comment: Cargo-cult 'bzero(buffer, 256);' :(

Comment: Please be aware that `read()` does not necessarily read as much as it was told to. Transferring larger amounts of data might reveal this to you. You want to loop around read until all you want had been read. Read `read()`'s documentation on reading from sockets closely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be interacting with a line-based service. Make sure you are including the newline `\n` or `\r\n` in your sent data.

Comment: "*Make sure you are including the newline \n*" The code shown does, as `fgets()` typically returns a new-line.

Comment: @alk: OP was saying that the `fgets` version worked while the `write(sockfd, "name", 5);` version did not work.